# Split a grid into shapes that can be moved back from 4 directions

Tags: algorithm, matrix, random, generated

Basically I have 4 grids Left, Right, Top, Bottom. Player can choose each of  them and move all the blocks on that grid to the Middle grid to fulfill it, like tetris from 4 directions:

> ```
>       |0 0 0|
>       |0 0 0|             (0 is empty, 1 is generated block)
>       |0 0 1| 
>        _ _ _         Bottom->Mid  Right->Mid  Top->Mid   Left->Mid     
> |0 0 0|0 0 0|0 1 0|    |1 0 0|     |1 1 0|     |1 1 1|    |1 1 1|  
> |0 0 0|0 0 0|0 1 1|    |1 0 0|     |1 1 1|     |1 1 1|    |1 1 1| -> Win! Generate 
> |1 0 0|0 0 0|0 1 1|    |0 0 0|     |0 1 1|     |0 1 1|    |1 1 1|    another game.
>        _ _ _
>       |0 0 0|
>       |1 0 0|
>       |1 0 0|
> ```

The point here is to make sure there is at least 1 way for player to combine all 4 grids.

What I've tried so far is generate the right order first (Left->Right->Top....), then generate all the blocks 1 by 1. When a block is generated, i perfomn a check with the generated order (move all the blocks in Left to Mid, then Right then Top...) to see if its still working, the code is similar to this:

```
// (left->right, top->right->botttom->left, top... it doesn't have to be all 4 directions)
Random the right direction order. 

Generate all possible coordinates from all the directions from the path above.
Initialize an empty list to store all chosen coordinates.

While(!(Generate enough x*x block))
{
    Get one coordinate from all possible coordinates

    if (Perform a check with the right order and the chosen list)
        Add it into the chosen list.

}
```

The problem here is a block can be wrong at this point, but it can become right when another block is generated:

> ```
>           |0 0 0|                                      |0 0 1|
>           |0 0 1|                                      |0 0 1|
>           |0 0 1|                                      |0 0 1|
>            _ _ _                                        _ _ _
>     |0 1 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|                          |0 1 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|
>     |1 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|                          |1 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|
>     |1 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|                          |1 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0|
>            _ _ _                                        _ _ _
>           |0 1 0|                                      |0 1 0|
>           |0 1 0|                                      |0 1 0|
>           |0 0 0|                                      |0 0 0|
>  At this point the logic is wrong          But if I add 1 more block to the
>   with Top->Left->Bottom order.               top grid, it'll become right.
> ```

**There is no way to check if the each block is right or wrong without re-calculate all the generated blocks logic**

So i want to ask if there a better way, algorithm to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more descriptive and provide code examples that can reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: I tried to add some infomation about the problem. The question still look dump because its hard to describe it in 1 sentence.